# Problem with table layout

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have three drop down list `<h:selectOneMenu>`, and a `<p:dataTable>`. I want the three drop down list to be side by side with the dataTable. As I have right now, The three drop down lists are above the dataTable. I try to create bigger table and put the three drop down lists in one column, and put `<h:dataTable>` in another column to get the side by side layout, but it does not work. Here is what I got so far

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="customer" value="#{DMBackingBean.customer}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Customer" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{DMBackingBean.customers}"/>
            <p:ajax actionListener="#{DMBackingBean.handCustomerChange}" update="facility" event="change"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="facility" value="#{DMBackingBean.facility}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Facility" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{DMBackingBean.facilities}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <br/><br/>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="project" value="#{DMBackingBean.project}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Projet" itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{DMBackingBean.projects}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{DMBackingBean.drawings}" selection="#{DMBackingBean.selectedDrawing}" selectionMode="single">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="DrawingType"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.drawingType}"/>
            </p:column>
            ...
        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Create a `h:panelGrid` and put the dropdowns in one `h:panelGroup`. The `h:panelGrid` renders a HTML `<table>` element with each child in its own `<td>` element.

   ```
   <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:selectOneMenu>...</h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:selectOneMenu>...</h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:selectOneMenu>...</h:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:dataTable>...</h:dataTable>
   </h:panelGrid>
   ```
2. Wrap the dropdowns in a `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`, it will render a HTML `<div>` element. Then apply CSS `float:left;` on both the `<h:panelGroup>` and the `<h:dataTable>`.

   ```
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="left">
        <h:selectOneMenu>...</h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu>...</h:selectOneMenu>
        <h:selectOneMenu>...</h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:dataTable styleClass="left">...</h:dataTable>
   ```

   with

   ```
   .left { float: left; }
   ```

Comment: I used your first method. And it works. However, when it generate the second <td> element for the <dataTable>, the <dataTable> is align center inside the <td> cell, make it look funny. Is there a way that I can make both of the <td> to align top?, I try to use `<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="vertical-align: top">`, but it does not work

Comment: Check the generated HTML output. It's applying the style on the `table` rather than the `td`. Give it a classname and use `.classname td { vertical-align: top; }` in CSS.